# how to make mongodb lookup match from both collection

Tags: mongodb

Database structure:

```
db={
  "collection": [
    {
      "key": 15,
      "name": "srk",

    },
    {
      "key": 12,
      "name": "suman",

    }
  ],
  "other": [
    {
      "key": 15,
      "name": "miki",
      "category": "dish"
    },
    {
      "key": 15,
      "name": "mira",
      "category": "air"
    },
    {
      "key": 15,
      "name": "manas",
      "category": "air"
    },
    {
      "key": 166,
      "name": "sibu",
      "category": "dish"
    }
  ]
}
```

query i am trying:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "other",
          localField: "key",
          foreignField: "key",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          key: 15,
          { "inventory_docs":
            { category: 'dish'}
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

I am not getting result here while making query in mongodb.

Please have a look , tell me where i am doing wrong in the query.

I am matching key with 15 from both the collections  and category with 'Dish' from foreign collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you have solved your problem self. 
but query needs to optimize

if you do Lookup first, you will get data of `"key": 12` or all other keys.

just to optimize query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
     $match : {  key: 15 }
  },
 {
  $lookup: {
    from: "other",
    localField: "key",
    foreignField: "key",
    as: "inventory_docs"
 }
},
{
   $unwind: "$inventory_docs"
},
{
  $match: {
     "inventory_docs.category": "dish"
    } 
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "other",
      localField: "key",
      foreignField: "key",
      as: "inventory_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$inventory_docs"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      key: 15,
      "inventory_docs.category": "dish"
    }
  }
])
```